# Is it possible to easly show local storage data for a cordova application installed on my phone from the Play Store?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, local-storage, ibm-cloud

IBM push message service gave me a "client-secret key" and I have to decide how to make it available on my cordova app for make the service work.
I am concerned about security.

I have 3 scenarios:

- Store the "client-secret key" hardcoded on the javascript code of my cordova application (but maybe, tell me if it's true, a medium skilled user can see html5 source code that resiedes inside my published apk and get the key)
- Always ask to a server for the "client-secret key" when I need it (it can happen frequently and make my app slower for the  requests)
- Ask the server to send the "client-secret key" once and save it inside local storage.

About the last point (to save the key on the local storage), for an app downloaded from the Play Store, are mobile user easily able to read local storage for apps installed on their phones? How?

Thanks

Marco

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to read the data which is stored in local storage of the device. This can be resolved by securing it with encryption before storing the `client-secret` key in to the local storage.

If you are trying on cordova, You can use [cordova-plugin-secure-key-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-secure-key-store) plugin to store the key securely in local storage.